# Problema de arboles binarios de busqueda Java

Tags: java, recursión

Me dan el siguiente problema que no logro realizar.

Implemente un método, que dado como parámetros un Árbol Binario de Búsqueda y 
  un valor,
  devuelve el valor inmediato mayor.

- Es decir, dado el siguiente árbol:
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

  - El valor inmediato mayo de **3** seria 8
  - El valor inmediato mayor de **14** podría devolver -1, porque no tiene
  - El valor inmediato mayor de **4** seria 6.

**NOTA: La solución debe estar implementada en java.**

Comment: Preguntas solicitando ayuda con trabajo escolar deben incluir un resumen del trabajo que has realizado hasta el momento para resolver el problema y una descripción de la dificultad que estás teniendo para resolverlo. Lee [ask] y [¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](/help/on-topic) para más información.

Answer (score 2):

El valor inmediato mayor de un árbol binario es el nodo hijo de su derecha. Es decir cuando estés posicionado en uno de los nodos poniendo como ejemplo el nodo 6, el resultado será el 7.
Este método te va a ayudar a desplazarte por los árboles y poder realizar operaciones sobre ellos.
Para poder hacer el ejercicio tienes que ver cómo tienes implementado el árbol, el modelo que yo aprendí fue con una lista enlazada y la distribución de los nodos era de tal forma:

- El nodo padre está en la posición i.
- El nodo hijo de la izquierda (el pequeño en un árbol binario de búsqueda) está en la posición 2i+1.
- El nodo hijo de la derecha (el grande en un árbol binario de búsqueda) está en la posición 2i+2.

Normalmente estas cosas se dan en la teoría de la asignatura estate atento hombre jeje ;)

Comment: Correcto, así es. Janzek, repasa la teoría y verás que estás equivocado en cuanto al concepto. El valor inmediato mayor de un elemento no es su raiz, sino su hijo derecho. Lo que tú propones, sería válido sólo para los hijos que bajan por la izquierda, ya que, los que bajan por la derecha, su raiz será siempre más pequeña. La implementación en Java es relativamente sencilla. [Aquí](https://www.baeldung.com/java-binary-tree) te dejo una sencilla. Un saludo.